# Collision detection in away3d 4.0

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I am creating some catching game using Away3D 4.0. There is some fruits falling from sky and need to catch using some basket. I am new to Away3D . How can detect the fruits falling from the sky is inside the Basket. is there any way to find the collision detection in away3d. Is `awayphysics` is the only answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this library but hope it will help you

[Basic collision detection](http://www.allforthecode.co.uk/aftc/forum/user/modules/forum/article.php?index=7&subindex=2&aid=130)

Answer (score 1):

If you need some kind of physics (bounce of fruit colliding with the basket) you should use AwayPhysics: https://github.com/away3d/awayphysics-core-fp11

Instead if you just need to check if the fruit is in the basket you should compare  x and y and bounds of the fruit and the basket.

I suggest you to use some physics library because it can handle all this for you.

- AwayPhysics is a 3D Physics Engine porting of [Bullet C++](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) and dedicated to Away3D.
- [JigLibflash](https://code.google.com/p/jiglibflash/) is a generic 3D Physics Engine porting of JigLib C++
- [Box2Dflash](http://www.box2dflash.org/) is a generic 2D Physics Engine porting of the famous [Box2D C++](http://box2d.org/)
- [Box2D flash alchemy port + WCK](http://www.sideroller.com/wck/) is another porting of Box2D C++

Enough?

FYI JigLib was the initial engine used by Away3D but then they made Awayphysics that's much better

Comment: i have tried awayphysics. Is there any other physics which will work smoothly with away3d.

Comment: Depends, AwayPhysics is a porting of Bullet Physics and it's integrated with Away in a strict way. If you need just 2 axis of physics (Platform 3D game) you can use Box2D

Comment: i tried bulletphysics. The problem it doesn't have any Documentation. And also it needs the latest player.

Comment: Bulletphysics cannot be used with flash. AwayPhysics is the porting of it.